# How to save sqlite db file of another android application.?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, apache-axis

i developed application for sales force in our company.most of them do sales in rural areas and more times no signal for those areas.then they tell us they synch their sales to server.but more sales details are lost.
then i try to develop tool as  third party tool for my app to save local db file to phone internal memory.then we can get it via email.here is code

```
    try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SD Card Detecting ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Backup is writing to SD card", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String currentDBPath = "//data//com.lk.lankabell.android.activity//databases//TSRDBNEW";
            String backupDBPath = "TSRDBNEW-Backup";
            File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

            if (currentDB.exists()) {
                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Backup is successful to SD card", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Backup is un-success to SD card", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

i used my main app [**android+ksoap+axis2**] technologies.

please advice me to implement this.i tried with above code.but it doesn't work.its need sd card too.any issue with my db url.?

[image]

Comment: Try to get the database path using this method: [getDatabasePath("TSRDBNEW")](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getDatabasePath%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: EDIT: i miss one important detail: is the same app. A good choice is use a SQLiteOpenHelper from your db, and then, do a query with an adapter.

Comment: dear LuS.where i have to add your code fragment.please can u add as answer.?

Comment: @PriyanRockZ replace String currentDBPath = ... with: File dbFile = getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath("TSRDBNEW"); and then String currentDBPath = dbFile.getAbsolutePath(); hope this will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "get" a file from data "private" folder of any app so easily. The best way is, as you do creating/updateing/deleting from your classes to the DB, create a new query that gets the information you want, save it as String, and then save in sdcard in a txt file, or json file, or some format that you want. It could be a possible solution (without DB model can't do more) using the CSV format:

```
public void generateTXTOnSD(String[] lines_txt) 
{
    // lines_txt contains an array of each register in CSV format.
    try
    {
        File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"NameOfDirectoryYouWantToSave");
        if (!root.exists()) 
        {
            root.mkdirs();
        }
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        // I made this to no override early versions of data I have stored.
        String hour= String.valueOf(cal.get(cal.HOUR_OF_DAY))+"_"+String.valueOf(cal.get(cal.MINUTE))+"_"+String.valueOf(cal.get(cal.SECOND));
        File txtfile = new File(root, name_txt+hour+".txt");
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(txtfile);
        //Every line contain the info you want to save
        for (String line_txt : lines_txt) {
            writer.append(line_txt);
            writer.append('\r');
            writer.append('\n');

        }
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();


    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        // ERROR

    }
}
```

Hope this helps.